# SQL Server query for total dollar amount of orders per customerID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables that I need to create a query for. I'm sure I'll need to join them as well.

I need to take the `CustomerName` and `Address` of customer from my `Customer` table but I also need the query to show the total dollar amount of all the orders placed by customer. So if the customer spent for example $300 dollars this year in total, that $300 is the output I'm trying to achieve.

I have a table called `Order Details` that uses an `OrderID` which is tied to a `CustomerID` and there are `unitprice` and `quantity` columns in the `Order Details` table. I'm trying to figure out how to multiple these but I am going crazy.

I have tried this to get at least the total from the orders but I have syntax errors for sure:

```
SELECT unitprice, 
       quantity 
FROM   [Order details] (unitprice * quantity) AS Totalorders, 
       from [Order Details] 
WHERE  orderid > 0
```

also this without any luck :

```
SELECT customers.companyname                                AS 'Company Name', 
       customers.address                                    AS 'Address', 
       [order details].unitprice * [order details].quantity AS 'Orders' 
FROM   customers 
       LEFT JOIN orders 
              ON customers.customerid = orders.customerid 
ORDER  BY customers.companyname, 
          customers.address, 
          orders
```

Thanks

Comment: Please be diligent when pasting code. I fixed some syntax errors for you.

Comment: Do you have two tables or three (Customers, Orders, Order details)?

Comment: Yes I have 4 tables actually. Customers,Order Details,Orders, and Products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join in the order details and do a group by aggregation:

```
SELECT c.CompanyName AS "Company Name",
       c.Address AS "Address",
       sum(od.Unitprice * od.quantity) as "Orders"
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID left join
     [Order Details] od
     on od.orderid = o.orderid
GROUP BY c.CompanyName, c.Address
ORDER BY c.CompanyName, c.Address
```

In addition, I made some stylistic changes.  I added aliases to the table names.  I find it much easier to read `c.CompanyName` rather than `Customers.CompanyName`.  I changed the delimiter on the column aliases to use double quotes rather than single quotes.  I associate single quotes with string constants inside the statement.

Comment: Actually I had to change the data types because it gave me a multiply error but this worked!! Thanks a Million!!!!

Answer (score 0):

if it s one-to-many relationship, your query will look something like:

```
SELECT
Customers.CompanyName AS 'Company Name',
Customers.Address AS 'Address',
SUM(O.Unitprice * O.quantity) as 'Orders'
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN [Order Details] O
ON Customers.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.CompanyName, Customers.Address
ORDER BY Customers.CompanyName, Customers.Address
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need but there isn't a CustomerID in the Order Details table. There is a CustomerID in my Orders table. I do have OrderID in both my Orders table and Order Details table.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. It would help if you have clearly specified this in your question